# Добавление символов к каждому слову ввода

Tags: python

Как в python к каждому слову из введенной строки добавить нужные буквы? Сейчас только к первому слову получается

```
vowels = 'бвгджзклмнпрстф'
word = input('Введи текст: ')

if word[0].lower() in vowels:
    word = 'ххе' + word
elif word[0].lower() not in vowels and word[0].startswith('а'):
    word = 'ххя' + word[1:]
elif word[0].lower() not in vowels and word[0].startswith('о'):
    word = 'ххё' + word[1:]
elif word[0].lower() not in vowels and word[0].startswith('э'):
    word = 'ххе' + word[1:]
elif word[0].lower() not in vowels and word[0].startswith('е'):
    word = 'хх' + word[0:]
elif word[0].lower() not in vowels and word[0].startswith('ю'):
    word = 'хх' + word[0:]
elif word[0].lower() not in vowels and word[0].startswith('я'):
    word = 'хх' + word[0:]
elif word[0].lower() not in vowels and word[0].startswith('и'):
    word = 'хх' + word[0:]
elif word[0].lower() not in vowels and word[0].startswith('у'):
    word = 'ххю' + word[1:]
print(word)
```

Результат: Ввожу фразу из нескольких слов (например: `вышел заяц погулять`). На выводе должна быть фраза: `ххевышел ххезаяц ххепогулять`

Comment: Как минимум, цикл нужен. Да разделение на слова. Тут пока проверка первой буквы введенного текста только.

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Дайте краткое описание, что делает ваш код или что вы пытаетесь достичь, какого результата

Comment: Результат: Ввожу фразу из нескольких слов (например: вышел заяц погулять). На выводе должна быть фраза: ххевышел ххезаяц ххепогулять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо разбить строку на слова при помощи метода split

```
vowels = 'бвгджзклмнпрстф'
word = input('Введи текст: ')

for w in word.split():
    if w[0].lower() in vowels:
        w = 'ххе' + w
    elif w[0].lower() not in vowels and w[0].startswith('а'):
        w = 'ххя' + w[1:]
    elif w[0].lower() not in vowels and w[0].startswith('о'):
        w = 'ххё' + w[1:]
    elif w[0].lower() not in vowels and w[0].startswith('э'):
        w = 'ххе' + w[1:]
    elif w[0].lower() not in vowels and w[0].startswith('е'):
        w = 'хх' + w[0:]
    elif w[0].lower() not in vowels and w[0].startswith('ю'):
        w = 'хх' + w[0:]
    elif w[0].lower() not in vowels and w[0].startswith('я'):
        w = 'хх' + w[0:]
    elif w[0].lower() not in vowels and w[0].startswith('и'):
        w = 'хх' + w[0:]
    elif w[0].lower() not in vowels and w[0].startswith('у'):
        w = 'ххю' + w[1:]
    print(w)
```

Результат:

```
Введи текст: вышел заяц погулять
ххевышел
ххезаяц
ххепогулять
```

Comment: Спасибо! Добавил еще в вывод end= ' ', чтобы в строку вывести.

Answer (score 1):

Добавлю решение, которое сокращает вашу реализацию. Я просто использую словарь, как сопоставление гласной и приставки, которая соответствует условию.

```py
pattern_0 = {
    "е": "хх",
    "ю": "хх",
    "я": "хх",
    "и": "хх",
}
pattern_1 = {
    "а": "ххя",
    "о": "ххё",
    "э": "ххе",
    "у": "ххю",
}
vowels = 'бвгджзклмнпрстф'

test_str = "вышел заяц погулять на опушку"
result = []
for word in test_str.split():
    if word[0].lower() in vowels:
        result.append('ххе' + word)
    elif word[0].lower() in pattern_0.keys():
        result.append(pattern_0[word[0]] + word)
    else:
        result.append(pattern_1[word[0]] + word[1:])

print(*result)
```

Вывод

```
ххевышел ххезаяц ххепогулять ххена ххёопушку
```

Comment: думал тоже предложить решение со слваорем чтобы избавиться от этого ужаса с if, но я так понял из кода автора вопроса, что если встречаются некоторые гласные буквы, то ее надо будет убрать. например у `'ххю' + w[1:]`

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin не сразу увидел(

Comment: словари явно более читабельные чем куча `if'ов` )

Answer (score 0):

вы также можете это сделать с помощью регулярного выражения, примерно так:

```
from re import sub

d = {"а":"я", "о":"ё", "у":"ю"}
word = input('Введи текст: ')

print(sub(r'\b\w', lambda m: f'xx{d.get(m[0],"e"*(m[0] not in "еюяи")+m[0])}', word))

>>> out
'''
Введи текст: вышли заяц, олень и удав погулять
xxeвышли xxeзаяц, xxёлень xxи xxюдав xxeпогулять
```